# Pointer address in a C multidimensional array

Tags: c, arrays, memory, pointers, multidimensional-array

I'm messing around with multidimensional arrays and pointers. I've been looking at a program that prints out the contents of, and addresses of, a simple array. Here's my array declaration:

```
int zippo[4][2] = { {2,4},
            {6,8},
            {1,3},
            {5,7}   };
```

My current understanding is that `zippo` is a pointer, and it can hold the address of a couple of other pointers. By default, `zippo` holds the address of pointer `zippo[0]`, and it can also hold the addresses of pointers `zippo[1]`, `zippo[2]`, and `zippo[3]`.

Now, take the following statement:

```
printf("zippo[0] = %p\n", zippo[0]);
printf("  *zippo = %p\n", *zippo);
printf("   zippo = %p\n", zippo);
```

On my machine, that gives the following output:

```
zippo[0] = 0x7fff170e2230
  *zippo = 0x7fff170e2230
   zippo = 0x7fff170e2230
```

I perfectly understand why `zippo[0]` and `*zippo` have the same value. They're both pointers, and they both store the address (by default) of the integer 2, or `zippo[0][0]`. But what is up with `zippo` also sharing the same memory address? Shouldn't `zippo` be storing the address of the pointer `zippo[0]`? Whaaaat?

Comment: Actually, I've never touched Java. I briefly put my toes into the water with BASIC and pascal, then jumped right in with C. C is the first and only language I've ever really tried learning.

What, is Java much higher-level, and therefore does not need to deal with this level of detail?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

When you declare a multidimensional array, the compiler treats it as a single dimensional array.  Multidimensional arrays are just an abstraction to make our life easier.  You have a misunderstanding: This isn't one array pointing to 4 arrays, its always just a single contigous block of memory.

In your case, doing:

```
int zippo[4][2]
```

Is really the same as doing

```
int zippo[8]
```

With the math required for the 2D addressing handled for you by the compiler.

For details, see this [tutorial on Arrays](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/) in C++.

This is very different than doing:

```
int** zippo
```

or

```
int* zippo[4]
```

In this case, you're making an array of four pointers, which could be allocated to other arrays.

Comment: Ahhh, this is a very clear explanation. Thanks. I'll do some reading on the difference between a simple multidimensional array (being a single, contiguous block of memory) and an array of pointers.

Answer (score 39):

When an array expression appears in most contexts, its type is implicitly converted from "N-element array of T" to "pointer to T", and its value is set to point to the first element in the array.  The exceptions to this rule are when the array expression is an operand of either the `sizeof` or address-of (`&`) operators, or when the array is a string literal being used as an initializer in a declaration.

Thus, the expression `zippo` "decays" from type `int [4][2]` (4-element array of 2-element arrays of int) to `int (*)[2]` (pointer to 2-element array of int).  Similarly, the type of `zippo[0]` is `int [2]`, which is implicitly converted to `int *`.

Given the declaration `int zippo[4][2]`, the following table shows the types of various array expressions involving zippo and any implicit conversions:

```
Expression    Type            Implicitly converted to  Equivalent expression
----------    ----            -----------------------  ---------------------
zippo         int [4][2]      int (*)[2]               
&zippo        int (*)[4][2]       
*zippo        int [2]         int *                    zippo[0]
zippo[i]      int [2]         int *
&zippo[i]     int (*)[2]                               
*zippo[i]     int                                      zippo[i][0]
zippo[i][j]   int
&zippo[i][j]  int *
*zippo[i][j]  invalid
```

Note that `zippo`, `&zippo`, `*zippo`, `zippo[0]`, `&zippo[0]`, and `&zippo[0][0]` all have the same value; they all point to the base of the array (the address of the array is the same as the address of the first element of the array).  The types of the various expressions all differ, though.

Comment: This really helps with my understanding of how many ways an array or pointer can be represented, and what it means for a statement to decay. Very thorough. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

`zippo` is not a pointer.  It's an array of array values.  `zippo`, and `zippo[i]` for `i` in 0..4 can "decay" to a pointer in certain cases (particularly, in value contexts).  Try printing `sizeof zippo` for an example of the use of `zippo` in a non-value context.  In this case, `sizeof` will report the size of the array, not the size of a pointer.

The name of an array, *in value contexts*, decays to a pointer to its first element.  So, in value context, `zippo` is the same as `&zippo[0]`, and thus has the type "pointer to an array [2] of `int`";  `*zippo`, in value context is the same as `&zippo[0][0]`, i.e., "pointer to `int`".  They have the same value, but different types.

I recommend reading [Arrays and Pointers](http://web.torek.net/torek/c/pa.html) for answering your second question.  The pointers have the same "value", but point to different amounts of space.  Try printing `zippo+1` and `*zippo+1` to see that more clearly:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int zippo[4][2] = { {2,4}, {6,8}, {1,3}, {5,7} };
    printf("%lu\n", (unsigned long) (sizeof zippo));
    printf("%p\n", (void *)(zippo+1));
    printf("%p\n", (void *)(*zippo+1));
    return 0;
}
```

For my run, it prints:

```
32
0xbffede7c
0xbffede78
```

Telling me that `sizeof(int)` on my machine is 4, and that the second and the third pointers are not equal in value (as expected).

Also, `"%p"` format specifier needs `void *` in `*printf()` functions, so you should cast your pointers to `void *` in your `printf()` calls (`printf()` is a variadic function, so the compiler can't do the automatic conversion for you here).

*Edit*: When I say an array "decays" to a pointer, I mean that the name of an array in value context is equivalent to a pointer.  Thus, if I have  `T pt[100];` for some type `T`, then the name `pt` is of type `T *` in value contexts.  For `sizeof` and unary `&` operators, the name `pt` doesn't reduce to a pointer.  But you can do `T *p = pt;`—this is perfectly valid because in this context, `pt` is of type `T *`.

Note that this "decaying" happens only once.  So, let's say we have:

```
int zippo[4][2] = { {2,4}, {6,8}, {1,3}, {5,7} };
```

Then, `zippo` in value context decays to a pointer of type: pointer to array[2] of `int`.  In code:

```
int (*p1)[2] = zippo;
```

is valid, whereas

```
int **p2 = zippo;
```

will trigger an "incompatible pointer assignment" warning.

With `zippo` defined as above,

```
int (*p0)[4][2] = &zippo;
int (*p1)[2] = zippo;
int *p2 = zippo[0];
```

are all valid.  They should print the same value when printed using `printf("%p\n", (void *)name);`, but the pointers are different in that they point to the whole matrix, a row, and a single integer respectively.

Comment: Let's see if I have this right: Even though `zippo` and `zippo[0]` point to different amounts of memory, their starting address is the same, and *in value contexts* they will both point to the first integer in zippo. Correct? And, is that what you mean by "decay"?

Comment: No. `zippo[0]` in value contexts is `int *`, and points to the first integer, where `zippo` in value contexts is "pointer to an array [2] of `int`".  You could do: `int (*p)[2]; p = zippo;` for example.  Then, `p[0] == 2` and `p[1] == 4`. For "decay", see my (soon to appear) edit.

Answer (score 2):

The important thing here is that `int zippy[4][2]` is not the same type of object as `int **zippo`.

Just like `int zippi[5]`, `zippy` is the address of a block of memory. *But* the compiler knows that you want to address the eight memory location starting at `zippy` with a two dimensional syntax, but want to address the five memory location starting at `zippi` with a one dimensional syntax.

`zippo` is a different thing entirely. *It* holds the address of a a block of memory big enough to contain two pointer, and if you make *them* point at some arrays of integers, you can dereference them with the two dimensional array access syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Very well explained by Reed, I shall add few more points to make it simpler, when we refer to `zippo` or `zippo[0]` or `zippo[0][0]`, we are still referring to the same base address of the array `zippo`. The reason being arrays are always contiguous block of memory and multidimensional arrays are multiple single dimension arrays continuously placed.

When you have to increment by each row, you need a pointer `int *p = &zippo[0][0]`, and doing `p++` increments the pointer by every row. 
In your example id its a 4 X 2 array, on doing `p++` its, pointer currently points to second set of 4 elements.