# How do I handle array pointers?

Tags: c, pointers, operator-keyword

This program prints all arrays outputs correctly.  But how does this program work exactly?  Why do we need address of `s[i]` here?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
        int s[4][2] = {{1234,1},{1233,2},{1232,3},{1331,4}};
        int (*p)[2];
        int i,j,*pint;

        for(i=0;i<4;++i){
                p = &s[i];
                pint = (int*)p;
                printf("\n");
                for(j=0;j<=1;++j)
                        printf("%d ",*(pint+j));
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please inline that code here, it's not very long at all.

Comment: To answer your question, frankly, it isn't needed at all.  The author of the code apparently doesn't like double-indexing, was demonstrating the different ways to work with pointers, or other reason.

Comment: i just want know how this stuff works..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int (*p)[2]` is a pointer to an `int [2]` type, which itself is essentially a `int *` type but with some additional type checking on the array bounds.

So in `p = &s[i];` you are setting `p` to be the address of the pointer to the area in memory where the array `s[i]` is.

It's much much easier to just make `p` also an array (i.e., "essentially" a pointer to an area in memory with additional machinery), and then use that directly to point at the array memory area (`p = s[i]`). However, in that case, that's exactly what `pint` (as a true pointer instead) is doing, so we can remove `p` entirely.

So:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
        int s[4][1] = {{1234,1},{1233,2},{1232,3},{1331,4}};
        int i,j,*pint;

        for(i=0;i<4;++i){
                pint = (int*)s[i];
                printf("\n");
                for(j=0;j<=1;++j)
                        printf("%d ",*(pint+j));
        }
        return 0;
}
```

See [Arrays and pointers](http://pw1.netcom.com/~tjensen/ptr/ch2x.htm) or google for "C arrays and pointers" and also [Pointer address in a C multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003745/pointer-address-in-a-c-multidimensional-array).

Note, I assume you are just doing this to play around and understand how pointers and arrays interact, so I make no comment on whether it is ideal to use pointers arithmetic or array notion and so on in each case.

---

Note also, that I say an array is "essentially a pointer [...]", however, this is not strictly true, it just acts like a pointer in a lot of cases and for the most part this is a reasonable way to think of how things are working. In reality, arrays are treated in a special way. See [Is array name equivalent to pointer?](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/c/threads/171080) and [Arrays](http://boredzo.org/pointers/#arrays).

Comment: "... make `p` also an array (i.e., also a pointer to an area in memory)"  No, arrays are **not** pointers.

Comment: Corrected and added a note at the end as well.

Comment: "So in `p = &s[i];` you are setting `p` to be the address of the pointer...". This is false. There is no pointer to take the address of in this context. This code makes `p` to point to an `int[2]` array. That arrays consists of two `int`s and nothing else. There's no pointer.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
        int s[4][2] = {{1234,1},{1233,2},{1232,3},{1331,4}};
        int (*p)[2];
        int i,j,*pint;

        for(i=0;i<4;++i){
                p = &s[i];
                pint = (int*)p;
                printf("\n");
                for(j=0;j<=1;++j)
                        printf("%d ",*(pint+j));
        }
        return 0;
}
```

here p is defined as an array which can store two integer values

```
 int (*p)[2];
```

in the outer for loop we use p array to store the 4  {1 dimensional} .  1 at a time .

```
 p = &s[i];
```

that is in first iteration it will be

```
p = &s[0] ;
i.e p = {1234,1}
```

the next iteration will be

```
 p = &s[1] ;
i.e p = {1234,2}
```

and so on. that is why we need &S[i]

the inner loop 
just iterate throug the 1 dimensional array to print the element

Answer (score 1):

Ugh.  I'm not sure what this code is supposed to illustrate other than how to make easy-to-understand code hard to understand.

`s` is a 4-element array of 2-element arrays of `int`.  That is, for `i` in 0..3, the type of `s[i]` is `int [2]` (which in most contexts decays to `int *`), and the type of `&s[i]` is `int (*)[2]`.

`p` is a pointer to a 2-element array of `int`.  Each time through the loop, `p` is assigned the address of the 2-element array at `s[i]`.

Finally, `pint` is a simple pointer to `int`, and each time through the loop is set to point to the first element in the array pointed to by `p`.  `*(pint + j)` is the long way of writing `pint[j]`.

Note that both `p` and `pint` are *entirely superfluous*; this is basically a long-winded way of writing

```
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
  for (j = 0; j < 2; j++)
    printf("%d ", s[i][j]);
  printf("\n");
}
```