# How to select an array of strings in C?

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

I want to define different arrays of strings in C, which then can be e.g. selected depending on some other value, i.e. like following:

```
char foo[][10] = {"Snakes", "on", "a", "Plane"};
char bar[][10] = {"Fishes", "in", "a", "Lake"};
char *choice;
if (flag == 1) {
  choice = &foo;
} else if (flag == 2) {
  choice = &bar;
} 
printf("%s%s\n", choice[0] , choice[1]);
```

Expected result in case `flag` is 1:

Snakeson

Expected result in case `flag` is 2:

Fishesin

But the above code gives a `segmentation fault` error, while I tried differnt definitions for `char`, i.e. `char*` and `char**`. How to do it right? Is there a good tutorial on this matter, i.e. on pointers, arrays, what `foo` exactly is in the above example...

Comment: see man page of printf. You are using it in a very wrong way!try printf("%s%s\n", choice[0] , choice[1]);

Comment: compile with warnings (gcc: `-Wall`)

Comment: @Maneolin - you are right - I updated the code. But error is still the same (`segmentation fault`).

Comment: Thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003745/pointer-address-in-a-c-multidimensional-array should really help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's easier if you just use arrays of pointers:

```
int main(void)
{
  const char *foo[] = { "Snakes", "on", "a", "Plane" };
  const char *bar[] = { "Fishes", "in", "a", "Lake" };
  const int flag = 17;
  const char **choice = (flag == 1) ? foo : bar;

  printf("%s %s\n", choice[0], choice[1]);

  return 0;
}
```

The above prints

```
Fishes in
```

Comment: Your suggestion seems to work! I will try it in the actual code.

Answer (score 2):

With arrays of char you need this:

```
char foo[][10] = {"Snakes", "on", "a", "Plane"};
char bar[][10] = {"Fishes", "in", "a", "Lake"};
char (*choice)[10];
if (flag == 1) {
    choice = &foo[0];
} else if (flag == 2) {
    choice = &bar[0];
} 
printf("%s%s\n", choice[0] , choice[1]);
```

For `choice[1]` to refer to the correct slot it has to be a pointer to the *array element* type and initialized to `&foo[0]` instead of `&foo`. Although they are the same address they are different data types.

---

If you want `choice` to be a pointer to the 2-dim char array, it can be done but you have specify both array dimensions when declaring the pointer and remember to dereference it:

```
char foo[][10] = {"Snakes", "on", "a", "Plane"};
char bar[][10] = {"Fishes", "in", "a", "Lake"};
char (*choice)[4][10];
if (flag == 1) {
    choice = &foo;
} else if (flag == 2) {
    choice = &bar;
} 
printf("%s%s\n", *choice[0] , *choice[1]);
```