# C: Call a variable from a multidimensional array using pointer

Tags: c

After some guys proved [`a[5] == 5[a]` is true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381542/with-c-arrays-why-is-it-the-case-that-a5-5a) as 
the C standard defines the `[]` operator as `a[b] == *(a + b)`

I've been thinking about a multidimensional array, for example:

```
int x[2][2]={
        {'A','B'},
        {'C','D'}};
```

I could echo the variables using `x[0][0]`, `x[0][1]`, `x[1][0]`, `x[1][1]` 
But how about using pointers?

Comment: Please, _please_, don't do that :)

Comment: The answer follows directly from the definition of `[]` that you mentioned.

Comment: I tried to do it, but I can't figure out so I ask...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003745/pointer-address-in-a-c-multidimensional-array

Comment: I don't how it happened that **This question may already have an answer here**

Comment: The answers to that question do a good job explaining what kinds of pointers to multidimensional arrays you can have, and how they are equivalent to indexing. What exactly is the question here?

Comment: @AShelly Rikayan Bandyopadhyay's answer works fine for `x[0][0]` and `x[0][1]`, but it gives an error for `x[1][0]` and `x[1][1]`. In where `*(*(x+1)+0)` supposed to echo `C` but it echoes `B`, also for `*(*(x+1)+1)` that supposed to echo `D`, it echoes `C`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are the answers:

```
x[0][0] ➜ *(x[0]+0) ➜ *(*(x+0)+0)
x[0][1] ➜ *(x[0]+1) ➜ *(*(x+0)+1)
x[1][0] ➜ *(x[1]+0) ➜ *(*(x+1)+0)
x[1][1] ➜ *(x[1]+1) ➜ *(*(x+1)+1)
```

**Explanation:**
Fetching/Echoing a value from inside an addrress uses the dereference pointer `*` and should follow the address where the values would come from.

Let's take `x[1][0]` as an example:

- We are fetching the address of `x[1]` + an offset value, or *how far we would move from the current address*, our offset is `0` and thus the address of `x[1][0]` using pointer is `x[1]+0`
  And to fetch the value would would add the `*` operator to call for the value inside the address and now we have `*(x[1]+0)`

But we still fetch the first address `x[1]` using square bracket `[]` operator, so using pointers...

- We would fetch `x[1][0]` using pointers by moving from offset to offset, the only thing we need to do now is to convert `x[1]` inside `*(x[1]+0)` so it would be `*(*(x+1)+0)`

[See it working, Click Here](http://ideone.com/bCK9YQ)
*The same process happens on multidimensional arrays*

**Also...** You can simply the equation whenever posssible

Can be simplified    : `*(*(x+0)+0)`  ➜  `*x`,
                             
`*(*(x+1)+0)`  ➜  `*(x+1)`
                             
`*(*(x+0)+1)`, ➜  `*(*x+1)`
Cannot be simplified : `*(*(x+1)+1)`

Reasons why? As have mentioned we are moving from one offset to another and *we're not adding the offset all together*

- `*(*(x+0)+0)` Obviously, did not move an offset so it could be simple as `*x`
- `*(*(x+1)+0)` This offset on the inner address have moved `*(x+1)` but the outer did not `+0` so it could be `*(x+1)` itself
- `*(*(x+0)+1)` This offset on the inner address did not moved `x+0` but the outer have moved `+1` so it could call the `*(x+0)` to be `*x` thus making it `*(*x+1)`
- `*(*(x+1)+1)` This one cannot be simplified anymore 'cause we need to move 1 offset on the inner pointer call and move 1 offset again afterwards.

Comment: Your answer works fine for `x[0][0]` and `x[0][1]`, but it gives an error for `x[1][0]` and `x[1][1]`. In where `*(*(x+1)+0)` supposed to echo `C` but it echoes `B`, also for `*(*(x+1)+1)` that supposed to echo `D`, it echoes `C`.

Comment: Sir, how then would I do it on `x[1][0]` and `x[1][0]`? Can you please update your answer?

Comment: `printf("%c %c\n",*(*(x+1)+0),x[1][0]);` both prints 'C'. What compiler are you using?

Comment: It works fine in Borland TurboC++ too. You might be doing something else wrong. Can you post a minimized version of your source code here?

Comment: Here http://ideone.com/DUWhgI

Comment: @Daniel Its not `*((*y+1)+0)` but `*(*(y+1)+0)`. Not `*((*y+1)+1)` but `*(*(y+1)+1)`, etc. See the answer.

Comment: Oh Sorry, A little operator precedence error has stirred me up, thanks!

Comment: Did the question that they linked to be duplicate really have answered my question? Cause I think it's a different thing...

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a Two Dimensional Array you should use * two time

```
*(*(x+0)+1)
```