# Is Str a "pointer" or a "pointer to pointer" in Str[Col][Row]?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Is `Str` a "pointer" or a "pointer to pointer" in `Str[3][5]`?

I usually declare `char **Str` to make a simulated 2D array, but how to send the address of `Str[3][5]` to another function, and how to set the parameter of that function in order to modify values in `Str[3][5]` ?

As far as I know, the compiler treats a 2D array as an ordinary array, so I should send `Str` (a pointer) to the other function. But how to modify the value of `Str[3][5]` via the received pointer?

Comment: A pointer to pointer is a kind of a pointer :)

Comment: I believe arrays are always passed by reference not value.

Comment: Yes. I want to know that how to modify the value of two-dimentional array by that passed pointer. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An array of T when used in most expressions will decay to a pointer of type "pointer to T" and have the value equal to the address of the first element of the array.

If `Str` is declared as:

```
char Str[3][5];
```

Then `Str` will decay to `char (*)[5]`, and have the value of `&Str[0]`. If passing to a function, you can declare the function as follows:

```
void foo (char (*str)[5], size_t n);
```

And within `foo()`, you would access `str` as you would access `Str` itself.

Answer (score 0):

[Pointer address in a C multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003745/pointer-address-in-a-c-multidimensional-array)

To expand on this answer to a similar question, when we type to get addresses of arrays. The name of the array is actually a pointer to the first variable in the array.

You can't really pass a pointer of a particular part of an array, as what we interact with in coding is the pointer itself. `(array + 1) == array[1]` Let's say we have create an array pointer `int* arrayPointer;` and you want to get the second variable in the array. You could either assign `arrayPointer = array + 1` or `arrayPointer = &array[1]`

So if you want to modify part of array[3][5] the easiest way is to pick that part of the array and assign a variable to it. For example if you want to modify the first "column" and first "row" you would type...

`array[0][0] = variable`

Hope this helps.

Comment: `array` is `&array[0]` actually.  (when not used as operand of unary `&` or `sizeof`)