# Converting multidimensional arrays to pointer notation

Tags: c, pointers

For the following value-of an array, I can do:

```
array[i][j][k] = *(*(*(array+i)+j)+k);
---------------------------------

int xar[3] = {1,2,3};
printf("%d | %d\n", xar[1], *(xar+1));

int xar2[2][3] = {{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}};
printf("%d | %d\n", xar2[1][2], *(*(xar2+1)+2));

int xar3[2][2][2] = {
                      {{1, 2},{3, 4}}, 
                      {{5, 6}, {7, 8}}
                    };
printf("%d | %d\n", xar3[1][1][1], *(*(*(xar3+1)+1)+1));
```

> 2 | 2 
> 6 | 6 
> 8 | 8

However, I'm having a tougher time trying to get the address of an array element and why that works, for example, if I have:

```
&array[i][j][k];
```

`array+i` gives me the equivalent of `&array[i]`, but then how would I grab the full inner item?

Comment: `*(*(array+i)+j)+k`

Comment: remove the first `*`

Comment: @ChrisDodd ok but could you please explain how that would work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pointer address in a C multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003745/pointer-address-in-a-c-multidimensional-array)

Comment: @Bob__ does my answer below look valid?

Comment: Yes, it sounds correct now, but please note that there may be some dupes around.

Answer (score 2):

Note that `&*array` will cancel each-other out, so we can do:

```
 array[i][j][k] =  *(*(*(array+i)+j)+k);
&array[i][j][k] = &*(*(*(array+i)+j)+k);   // &* can be eliminated
&array[i][j][k] =    *(*(array+i)+j)+k;
```